# Testing if subpopulation group is different from population group

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, group-differences

Say I have data about the distribution of age groups in a country:

```
0-10 y : 20% of pop (or 3,000,000 people out of 15,000,000 total)
10-20 y : 30% of pop
etc.
```

There's also data for each city in the country(total city population and age group totals). Now I'd like to see whether for a particular city a particular age group is significantly different from the country population e.g. in city X there are 15,000 people aged 10 to 20 out of a total city population of 100,000 people.

I can see how chi squared could be used to test whether a city's entire population distribution is different from the country's, but how would I go about finding out if only a particular age group in a city is different?

Answer (score 2):

This essentially reduces the question to a $2 \times 2$ contingency table (number in given age group, number in all other age group, for both the city and the country). Then you can simply test whether the proportion of the specific age group in the city is different from that of the country, with a test that is appropriate given the circumstances, such as sizes, expected cell counts (e.g. `prop.test` in R). Don't forget to subtract the city's numbers from the country-total, so that the two won't be dependent.

Comment: If you subtract out the subset from the total, you get a proper 2x2 instead of having to assume the subset is small and ignoring the dependence.

Comment: @Glen_b : Ah, of course! How could I overlook this. I edit the answer!